# Remove a Java version and keep other installed versions

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, cluster-computing, java-home

I have a ubuntu machine and have java-11 installed. My whole project consists of integrating a Hadoop cluster to work with Apache Drill and Apache Superset. I initially got Apache Drill running with Java -11. Then when configuring the Hadoop Cluster the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org) stated that Hadoop only supports java-8. So I downloaded java-8 through Oracle and changed the `JAVA_HOME` to the Java-8's path.

Then Hadoop worked fine. But then going back to drill it didn't work. I assume it must be due to the two java versions conflicting. I checked out websites like https://novicestuffs.wordpress.com/2017/04/25/how-to-uninstall-java-from-linux/ only to realize that if I follow them I would be completely removing java-8 and java-11 from my machine

Therefore is there a way I can permanently remove java-11 but keep java-8 in my system?

Comment: Drill requires JDK 8 to run, as stated here: http://drill.apache.org/docs/distributed-mode-prerequisites/ Is there any particular reason to keep Java 11? Hadoop best practices state that you have to have the same Java version on all cluster nodes.

Comment: No I don't want java-11 in my machine and I want to get rid of java-11 but keep java-8. Yes I should change the java version in all my nodes.